# Will entity fill default values into db?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I had a nullable field in my model. I changed it to be required and non-nullable. New records get set correctly, but is there anyway to have existing records have their field be updated?

In the context file I have the following:

```
builder.Entity<Player>()
    .Property(p => p.Notifications)
    .HasDefaultValue(NotificationPreference.Both);
```

EDIT:

So if I manually do an ef migration on localhost all the fields are updated correctly. Is there a way I can do this from the azure portal? I was under the impression that this would be done automatically. But it doesn't seem like it does.

Comment: Do you use EF Migrations?

Comment: Yes that's what I found odd. It seemed to work on my localhost but once on azure it didn't seem to set the default values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must update the values for other code to work, then do it directly on the SQL server as a one-off.

If you write code to automatically run through and set every time it's hit, you run the risk that months from now that code will be forgotten and may eventually produce an outcome you don't want (it's also inefficient)

A better way to handle this *may* be to set the default value in the get of the property by the `??` coalescing operator if EF sets a null, allowing the property to remain read-write, but **with a backing field**. This approach makes it explicit to others what the default value is.

A sample of a class with a property with a backing field:

```
public class Person
{
  private int? age;

  public int? Age
  {
    get
    {
       return this.age ?? -1; // if (Age == 0) would be true otherwise as default(int) would be used
    }

    set
    {
       this.age = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I wanted to avoid explicitly putting in code to set all the data. I'm also a little wary of setting the values on production. I would have thought the ef db migrations would have taken care of it with the code first approach. What do you mean by the backing field?

Comment: @user6728767 answer updated to show what is meant be backing field -- `age` is the backing field for the property `Age`.  The desired default value is applied in the property *getter*.

Comment: So the backing field would be necessary? Is there a way to run a db migration from azure? When I do it locally, all the values seem to update automatically when I do 'dotnet ef database update'

Comment: @user6728767 you do **not** want to do a migration on production data.  A backing field lets you control the get/set on the property when it is used by a client. I tend to do most things in the _getter_ so that I can keep the original values in the backing fields -- there are cases where adjusting in the set makes sense, BUT the order of access may matter (e.g. start and end dates)

Comment: If i'm using the `{get; set; }` shortcuts is there a way I can use the backing field on that? or do I have to explicitly define getters/setters on each.

Comment: @user6728767 the notation is syntactic sugar for a compiler-generated backing field. You will need to declare your own field and write explicit `get` and `set` bodies